# Annotation for uppercase and trim String

Tags: java, string, annotations

I have this code which `str` must be upper case and trimmed.

```
class A {
   private String str;

   public String getStr() { return str};

   public void setStr(String str) {
      if(str == null || str.equals(""))
           this.str = str;
      else 
           this.str = str.toUpperCase().trim();
   }

}
```

What I'm looking for is to make it annotation based. Which could be used either as 
`@UpperCaseTrim private String str;` or `@UpperCaseTrim public void setStr(String str) {...};`. 
How could this be implemented, maybe in a best way? What would the annotation processor be?

Comment: The option you have is likely to be the quickest and simplest.  If you are developing your own library and have a few hours to kill you could create an annotation processor.

Comment: Unless the annotation is necessary, id avoid it

Comment: A duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195757/creating-custom-annotation-in-java-to-force-upper-or-lower-case ?

Answer (score 1):

To make things simple and reusable, use a static utility method:

```
public class MyUtils {
    public static String upperCaseTrim(String str) {
        return str == null ? null : str.toUpperCase().trim();
    }
}
```

then:

```
public void setStr(String str) {
    this.str = MyUtils.upperCaseTrim(str);
}
```

or with static import:

```
public void setStr(String str) {
    this.str = upperCaseTrim(str);
}
```