# Non-blocking ODBC calls in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, java-6

I use pretty standard Java ODBC functionality - grab a `Connection` from the pool, create a `Statement` and execute it.

Our use-case is a game, logging game progress - ODBC calls are largely calls to stored procedures and in most cases there are no return values. So the fact the ODBC call blocks is annoying - the game is already turn based but users can see longer pauses if the DB is slow.

If I don't need to check the result of an ODBC call, is there any built-in functionality to execute the statement asyncronously? If not, what is a good way to do this without writing lots of code? I DO still need to catch ODBC exceptions when and if they occur.

This question looks related although not identical... [Is asynchronous jdbc call possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087696/is-asynchronous-jdbc-call-possible)

Comment: Why not execute the JDBC calls in a separate `Thread`?

Comment: That's kind of the question. If you think that's the best approach then please provide an example how to run an existing block of JDBC code in a thread.

Comment: Would like to reply, but first - are you using JDBC to connect to ODBC datasource (a type 1 JDBC driver, aka JDBC-ODBC bridge)?  Is your datasource MS Access or similar?

Comment: Data source is MySQL, I can't remember the different driver types but I use mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar and the MySQL classes to get a `java.sql.Connection`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's assume you have a `OdbcCaller`:

```
public class OdbcCaller {

public void callODBC() {
    // call ODBC directly
    // ...
}
```

You can wrap it in a runnable task and submit the task to a thread pool to make it executes asyncronously:

```
public void asyncCallODBC() {
    // wrap the call with a runnable task
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            callODBC();
        }
    });
    // the above line would return immediately.
}
```

The `executor` is a thread pool implementation provided by JDK, it could be defined as follows:

```
Executor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(/* core pool size */5,
        /* maximum pool size */10,
        /* keepAliveTime */1,
        /* time unit of keepAliveTime */TimeUnit.MINUTES,
        /* work queue */new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10000),
        /* custom thread factory */new ThreadFactory() {
            private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                Thread t = new Thread(r, "asyncCaller-" + (counter.incrementAndGet()));
                return t;
            }
        },
        /*
         * policy applied when all tasks are occupied and task
         * queue is full.
         */new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` is highly configurable and is welled documented in [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), you might want read it first.

Following are some sugguestion of thread pool configurations based on my experiences:

- The proper thread pool size is depending on the scenario, you may need run some tests to tune it.
- The work queue is used to cache the tasks when there are no available worker threads. A unbounded queue is not a good idea as you might run out your memory.
- It is a good practice to provide a `ThreadFactory` and give the threads a meaningful name. It will be very useful when you need to inspect threads states(using `jstack` or other tools).
- The reject policy is applied when no resources is available. You can choose one of the build-in policy(reject, discard, caller-run, discardOldest), or implement your own policy.

Comment: So every method on my DAO class has to be converted to a separate `OdbcCaller` class... no way to simply wrap a method call with a C#-like delegate or anything?

Comment: You can use `AOP` to avoid creating class of every DAO classes, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325640/aspect-oriented-programming-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Snippet
{
    static int i = 0;



    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
    {
        ExecutorService eventExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        final Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:url", "user",
                "password");
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    CallableStatement s = c
                            .prepareCall("{ call your_procedure(?) }");
                    s.setInt(1, i);
                    s.execute();
                } catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        for (; i < 100; i++)
            eventExecutor.submit(r);
    }
}
```

Runs the call to your_procedure 100 times with 100 different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EJB 3.1, you can create a `@Stateless` EJB, and mark one of the methods `@Asynchronous`. This is an out-of-the-box solution for Enterprise Java environment (*There* the external management of `Thread` resources are not recommended).

Comment: Plain old Java I'm afraid - it's a server app not a web app.

Comment: Whats the difference between an HTTP server and a webapp?

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about this but maybe you can use an aynsctask? That handles db stuff in a different thread

Comment: When I search for `aynsctask` I only get results for Android. Is it a Java-6 class or a generic term?